# Mysql query formation error in calculating total time taken by particular projects

Tags: mysql

I am not able to phrase the mqsql query for the shown table and values. I want the output as shown. The below values are in tabular form .

```
**Name | Time**           

  RWS  |         1                   
  CMS  |        2                
  JT    |       2                
  CMS  |         1      
  RWS  |         2

  JT    |        1
  RWS   |        1
```

I want the output as

```
**Name | time**

RWS |      4

CMS  |     3

JT    |    3
```

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: I have shared. Please try to understand it in a tabular form

Comment: Untested but should work `SELECT Name, SUM(TIME)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Name` Basically you need to learn [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `SUM()` aggregate function along with a `GROUP BY` clause like

```
select `Name`, sum(`Time`) as `Time`
from table1
group by `Name`
```

Comment: Can you pls give me complete query. i am new to sql

Comment: @asthasharma, that is the complete query per your posted question and data.

Comment: Oh yes. thank you very very much @Rahul